# Can not install packages on R Version 4.0.0

Tags: r, package, installation, version

I just updated my R version as shown [here](https://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) and now I can not use my packages. I tried to remove and reinstall them but I still get an error. For example, trying to install `tidyverse` gives me

```
install.packages("tidyverse")

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tidyverse’ is not available (for R version 4.0.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  internet routines cannot be loaded
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa) question but the steps in the answer did not help. Some steps do not apply to my situation and trying to run some of the steps results in the very same error.

Comment: Did you try another repository?

Comment: @cory Yes, I tried in `Enter one or more numbers separated by spaces and then ENTER, or 0 to cancel` all:
`1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` and then to install `install.packages("tidyverse")` but the error is the same.

Comment: The page you linked to is 7 years old, and may not have done a proper install.  I'd uninstall it completely, then re-install following the current instructions from `https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base`.

Comment: You have to do a clean install of all user packages for R 4.0.  Here's a link that shows how to do it: https://www.r-bloggers.com/get-all-your-packages-back-on-r-4-0-0/  The process worked for me just fine.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks! I ran `installr::uninstall.R("4.0.0", GUI = TRUE)`and now I at least can run all I want in my old version!